# The "Transitivity of Auto-Specialization in GHC" and "Specialization with Constraints" questions

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

See [Specialization with Constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21071706/specialization-with-constraints) and [Transitivity of Auto-Specialization in GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502335/transitivity-of-auto-specialization-in-ghc)

These questions have been lingering unanswered for a long time now. There's long conversations about them and on quick look, the synopsis seems to be that someone in the know turned up and told the OP that it's a known bug and to follow the bug tracker for more info.

It doesn't seem that they're ever going to get closed off.

What will happen with these questions ultimately?

Comment: It might be worth noting that there are a whole bunch of *deleted* answers on each of those questions.  Many are link-only, but a few are comprehensive, though downvoted.

Answer (score 4):

Either they get answered, or they don't. Nothing else will happen.

Asking a hard question is *fine*. Not getting answers is a pity, but that doesn't mean anything has to happen to these posts.

Comment: But it seems there either is no answer or the answer is already there in the comments. So will these two questions just permanently remain a feature of the "Unanswered" posts section of SO?

Comment: @i-CONICA: Then they'll just feature permanently in the Unanswered section. And that is *not a problem*.

Comment: Without wanting to sound terse - surely over time we'll just end up with a stack of similarly unanswerable questions and people will have to click to page 2 to get to the usual queue of reasonably answerable questions they might be able to help with?

Comment: We've been around for nearly 6 years now. If that was going to be a real problem we'd already have seen it happen already. This is really rather rare to have such highly voted unanswered questions.

Comment: Exactly, I've been here for 4.5 of them, nearly the same time as you. Hence my raising it as a possible anomaly or something that might need some attention. If we've just got to sit it out until someone takes the jist of the comments and posts them as an answer, then so be it. :)